# Serialization - class loading

Tags: java, serialization

serialVersionUID is used to ensure that during deserialization the same class (that was used during serialize process) is loaded. My doubt is when the class is loaded??
E.g SerialTry implements Serializeable

```
ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("serial"));
SerialTry st = (SerialTry)is.readObject();
```

As per this eg, when SerialTry is loaded? readObject() does the job of reading serialVersionUID from file and compare with serialVersionUID of the loaded class(I have not mentioned in code so JVM will create @ runtime is my understanding)??

Comment: That’s a weird question. Classes are loaded on their first use so in your code when you say `new Foo()` the class `Foo` will be loaded regardless of whatever you will do at a later time with Serialization. What else do you expect? The JVM to predict that you will do some Serialization in the future and therefore decide to create instances of a class without loading it? Besides the impossibility of that idea: why should it do that?

Comment: That's not what serialVersionUID does. serialVersionUID only ensures that the class in the classpath (already loaded or not) still has the same serialVersionUID as it had when the object was serialized, and throws an exception if not. It won't load an older version of the same class.

Comment: I never said it will load an older version of the class.. My question was in the above snipet, when SerialTry will be loaded??

Comment: It will be loaded the first time it's used, i.e. the first time the application needs to load the byte code of the class (to access one of its fields, or to create an instance of it, or to have a reference to the class, or whatever).

Answer (score 0):

The class definition will be loaded (as in made available for the JVM) from the start of the program (due to the import of the class or the class being in the classpath). The object will be generated in is.readObject().

Casting of non-primitive types doesn't change their actual types but only the dynamic type, so what the JVM sees it as, not what it is (if you cast an Audi to Car it will be an Audi nonetheless, so it doesn't change what it is but what it is handled as). So the Object is of the class SerialTry before it is casted to SerialTry.